# Delete documents in Solr by query

Tags: solr, solr4

I work on a rather complex Solr core with about 100 fields and about 6 million documents.
When I submit a query like 
`-ean:* and type:(-set and -series) and -title:* and -aggregatorId:*`
I get about 20.000 results. But when I use the exact same query for deletion, none of these records gets deleted.

As usually delete queries work on my system and I use Solr 4.8, it is not the issue from 
[Solr index update by query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192806/solr-index-update-by-query).
I use a simple master slave configuration, no SolrCloud.

Is there something special with this query? Too much negations or whatever? And what can I do to delete the records resulting from this query?

And yes, I know that Solr 4 is not state of the art; but upgrading to Solr 6 is currently not an option.

Comment: could you show your java code or http request? do you have something in logs?

Comment: I do this from the Solr admin page (Documents, XML: <delete><query>...</query></delete>. And no, I have nothing in the logs.

Comment: could try to send curl request in XML, so escaping etc. will be correct?

Comment: Since you only have negative terms, there is nothing for the query to subtract them from. I guess you need a `*:*` in the front there, since the regular `q=` appends one (hidden) for you if you don't have it.. Be careful about `and` vs `AND` as well

Comment: @MatsLindh Sounds reasonable, but unfortunately still does not work. As query it delivers the same results, as delete query it deletes nothing when I prepend a `*:* and`.

Comment: are you commiting? would be a huge duh! but as don't think anyone asked...just making sure

Comment: `type:(-set and -series)` seems an odd way to phrase this. Have you tried `-ean:* and -type:set and -type:series and -title:* and -aggregatorId:*`?

Comment: @Persimmonium Yes, I do commit. Solr is set to autocommit after 1 second, and even a manual commit changes nothing.